# delete[] operator causes segmentation fault in very simple case

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a very strange segmentation fault that occurs when I call `delete[]` on an allocated dynamic array (created with the `new` keyword). At first it occurred when I deleted a global pointer, but it also happens in the following very simple case, where I `delete[] arr`

```
int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
     double * arr = new double [5];
     delete[] arr;
}
```

I get the following message:

```
*** Error in `./energy_out': free(): invalid next size (fast):  0x0000000001741470 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Apart from the `main` function, I define some fairly standard functions, as well as the following (defined before the `main` function)

```
vector<double> cos_vector()
{
    vector<double> cos_vec_temp = vector<double>(int(2*pi()/trig_incr));
    double curr_val = 0;
    int curr_idx = 0;
    while (curr_val < 2*pi())
    {
        cos_vec_temp[curr_idx] = cos(curr_val);
        curr_idx++;
        curr_val += trig_incr;
    }

    return cos_vec_temp;
}

const vector<double> cos_vec = cos_vector();
```

Note that the return value of `cos_vector`, `cos_vec_temp`, gets assigned to the global variable `cos_vec` before the main function is called.

The thing is, I know what causes the error: `cos_vec_temp` should be one element bigger, as `cos_vec_temp[curr_idx]` ends up accessing one element past the end of the vector `cos_vec_temp`. When I make `cos_vec_temp` one element larger at its creation, the error does not occur.  But I do not understand why it occurs at the `delete[]` of `arr`. When I run gdb, after setting a breakpoint at the start of the `main` function, just after the creation of `arr`, I get the following output when examining contents of the variables:

```
(gdb) p &cos_vec[6283]
$11 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double> >::value_type *)  0x610468

(gdb) p arr
$12 = (double *) 0x610470
```

In the first gdb command, I show the memory location of the element just past the end of the `cos_vec` vector, which is `0x610468`. The second gdb command shows the memory location of the `arr` pointer, which is `0x610470`. Since I assigned a `double` to the invalid memory location `0x610468`, I understand it must have wrote partly over the location that starts at `0x610470`, but this was done before `arr` was even created (the function is called before `main`). So why does this affect `arr`? I would have thought that when `arr` is created, it does not "care" what was previously done to the memory location there, since it is not registered as being in use.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

**NOTE:**

`cos_vec_temp` was previously declared as a dynamic double array of size `int(2*pi()/trig_incr)` (same size as the one in the code, but created with `new`). In that case, I also had the invalid access as above, and it also did not give any errors when I accessed the element at that location. But when I tried to call `delete[]` on the `cos_vec` global variable (which was of type `double *` then) it also gave a segmentation fault, but it did not give the message that I got for the case above.

**NOTE 2:**

Before you downvote me for using a dynamic array, I am just curious as to why this occurs. I normally use STL containers and all their conveniences (I almost NEVER use dynamic arrays).

Comment: Your `cos_vector` is overrunning the vector. Try `push_back` instead to avoid manually calculating the size.

Comment: You identify the UB, and UB is UB...

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read **[How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**  At least leave us with a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by πάντα ῥεῖ™)

Comment: Heap corruption often manifests itself long after the corruption happens. This might cause some unrelated heap operation to fail.

Comment: @nneonneo see note 2 that I added above

Comment: @JoachimPileborg did you read the whole question? I know that that causes the error. I am asking why this occurs only at the `delete []` statement in `main`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did use gdb, please see the output that I provided. I am just asking this question out of curiousity

Comment: @KonradKapp If you had used `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access your vector, your code would have thrown an `out_of_range` exception instead of just leaving you in the dark with a segmentation fault or undefined behavior.

Comment: @KonradKapp Also, and on a side note, your vector is using floating point computation to determine the initial size.  That said, your vector may have a differing size depending on compiler, compiler options, etc., since floating point is not exact.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie did you read the whole question? I am asking WHY this is occuring only at the `delete []` operator (and I know that I am accessing an element that is out of bounds....)

Comment: @KonradKapp _"I am just asking this question out of curiousity"_ That's not such a good reason to ask here probably.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what kind of questions should be asked then?

Comment: @KonradKapp: you're curious why it fails. Overrunning a dynamically-allocated object results in a *heap overflow*, which can overwrite other heap objects or heap metadata used to track allocations. The resulting corruption can only be detected later, potentially long after the initial overrun.

Comment: @KonradKapp -  Your overwrite *in this circumstance* probably corrupted the heap.  If you compiled your code with a differing option, maybe you don't get an error in the `delete[]` call.  So are you going to spend time chasing this issue, or just accept it as bad code and move on writing correct code?

Comment: The `delete[]` operator happens to be at the end of `main`, so that's where the unrelated error pops up. Does it make a difference if you put a different code?

Comment: @KonradKapp You may want to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nothing on that page gives me any indication that asking something out of curiousity is bad on this site. Maybe my title is not the best, I admit, but I find it hard to understand why you are against me asking something that could increase my understanding of how things work on the lower level...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I did have code after it and before it, and it always occurs when I delete my first dynamically allocated array. Others have indicated that my out of bounds access in the `cos_vector` function may have corrupted the heap, which seems likely

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't write code like this. I almost NEVER use a dynamic array with `new`, and I normally use `push_back` with `vectors`. I was merely curious. I do not understand why some stackoverflow users are so against me just trying to understand how this works on the lower level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many heap allocators have meta-data stored next to the memory it allocates for you, before or after (or both) the memory. If you write out of bounds of some heap-allocated memory (and remember that `std::vector` dynamically allocates off the heap) you might overwrite some of this meta-data, *corrupting* the heap.

None of this is actually specified in the C++ specifications. All it says that going out of bounds leads to undefined behavior. What the allocators do, or store, and where it possibly store meta-data, is up to the implementation.

---

As for a solution, well most people tell you to use `push_back` instead of direct indexing, and that *will* solve the problem. Unfortunately it will also mean that the vector needs to be reallocated and copied a few times. That can be solved by [reserving](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) an approximate amount of memory beforehand, and then let the extra stray element lead to a reallocation and copying.

Or, or course, make better predictions for the actual amount of elements the vector will contain.

Comment: +1: Thanks for giving the first decent answer (i.e. for answering the actual question I was posing). Yes, I know I should  `push_back` (I normally use that, otherwise I reserve memory as you also recommend, but to a lesser extent).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are writing past the end of the vector allocated in the function executing before main, causing undefined behavior later on.

You should be able to fix the problem by rounding the number up when allocating the vector (casting to int rounds the number down), or using push_back instead of indexing:

```
cos_vec_temp.push_back(cos(curr_val));
```

Comment: You did not read the whole question....sigh....don't worry neither is anyone else, judging from the comments. Gonna close this soon.

Comment: @KonradKapp Too bad, because using push_back will probably fix it :-)